# Parse .ics file in iphone

Tags: iphone, icalendar

How to parser .ics file in iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing public on the iPhone to parse .ics files. You have to use a third party lib like [libical](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeassociation/)

Comment: How to implement it in my application (How to use third party lib)

Comment: There are some samples when you download the libical src.
In the README is an howto compile the lib. But be aware that you have to link static against the lib on the iPhone. You can't link dynamic on the iPhone.